# Formatting on “What topics can I ask about here?” is off

Tags: bug, design

The [Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?"](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has some formatting issues:

- There's an '#On-topic' halfway the page which is supposed to be a header (like Off-Topic above):

  [image]
- The item about LaTeX (at about three quarters of the page) seems to be mixed up with keyboard formatting:

  [image]

Especially the first one may be caused by the [CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/295232); ♦ moderators can edit this page and make sure it looks nice again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention. The page was already edited to fix this issue.